Cannot connect to server which provides certificate signed using SHA1 and RSA (linux, openssl 3)
I have legacy SqlServer to which I try to connect to, but connection fails because of TLS handshake error. After analyzing traffic with Wireshark it seems I found the reason: certificate is signed using Algorithm Id: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 (sha1WithRSAEncryption). So if client indicates rsa_pkcs1_sha1 (0x0201) support (using signature_algorithms extension in Client Hello) server responds correctly (was tested on Windows), otherwise server just closes connection immediately. However I didn't managed to enable it using openssl 3.
TLS version: 1.2
What I tried:

Set SECLEVEL=0 (CipherString = ALL@SECLEVEL=0)
Added CypherSuites which was accepted in successfull connection test (like TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x003c))
Ensured legacy provider is loaded and active (using openssl list -providers)
Explicitly added desired algorithm in SignatureAlgorithms. But not sure I did it correctly. Like this: SignatureAlgorithms = RSA+SHA1:ecdsa_sha1:rsa_pkcs1_sha1:...
config_diagnostics = 1
Ensured that RSA and SHA1 are usable in different context (openssl dgst -sha1 ./file.txt, openssl genrsa)

Still all related to SHA1 is skipped from signature_algorithms extension when TLS-handshake starts and therefore connection closed by server.
Also, for some reason openssl list -digest-algorithms prints sha1WithRSAEncryption => SHA1 in Legacy section, not in Provided section. It's not clear for me from docs, what this sections mean
openssl version: 3.2.2
P.S. Please keep in mind that I'm not competent in CypherSuites, signature algorithms and so on and how this affects each other. Just trying to connect to server.
P.S 2. PLEASE, do not tell me SHA1 is insecure, and I need update certificate on server I do not own.

What is your SSH client, version, and OS? Assuming basic OpenSSH client, you should generally be changing settings in ssh_config and not messing with openssl. Take a look at https://www.openssh.com/legacy.html for where to enable legacy KexAlgorithms for example

No, I have web app (ASP.NET) deployed on CentOS, which must connect to SqlServer on different host. SSH works fine.

“do not tell me SHA1 is insecure, and I need update certificate on server I do not own.” - Even if that’s likely the reason you cannot connect?

So the solution turned out to be distribution-specific. I use CentOS 9. Admin said he used this command: update-crypto-policies --set DEFAULT:SHA1. It seems it modified openssl config like this:
/etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/opensslcnf.config:
# add signature algorithms
SignatureAlgorithms = ...:ECDSA+SHA1:RSA+SHA1
Groups = ...

# add this lines
[openssl_init]
alg_section = evp_properties

[evp_properties]
rh-allow-sha1-signatures = yes

Note that in this case config changes that described in question is not needed.
If you not using CentOS / Red Hat, that maybe this answer  help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75766335/3602201 or issue it refers to: https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/20526#issuecomment-1472248209. In short, openssl should be compiled with option enable-weak-ssl-ciphers which is not set by default. I didn't validate if it works as the first solution is more suitable for me.
